# "<" operator not giving expected output in Python

Tags: python, operators

Here is my python function:

```
def fifo(pageframes, pagereferencestring):
    pages = len(pagereferencestring)
    queue = []
    pagefaults = 0

    for each in pagereferencestring:
        if each not in queue:
            pagefaults += 1
            print len(queue)
            print pageframes
            if len(queue) < pageframes:
                print "hello"
                queue.append(each)
            else:
                queue = queue[1:]
                queue.append[each]
            print queue
    print "FIFO mode : " + str(pagefaults)
```

I am inputting pageframes = 3, and pagereferencestring = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], and so pages = 16

Here is the output I am getting:

```
0


3


hello



[1]



1


3


hello


[1, 2]



2


3


hello


[1, 2, 3]


3


3


hello


[1, 2, 3, 4]


FIFO mode : 4
```

Here is my question: As is clear from the output, even when len(queue) == pageframes (=3), the control is entering the if condition (which should happen only if len(queue) < pageframes). Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see `==` anywhere in your code

Comment: I meant the "<" operator. Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: you have syntax error in your code, are you sure you are copy/pasting correctly?

Comment: I fixed the append statement. Still getting the same output.

Comment: remove the blank line before the "for" and make sure your tabs/indents are correct.

Comment: However, I changed pageframes to int(pageframes) in the comparison statement, and it gives me the correct output. Any idea why?

Comment: lol. is pageframes a string?

Comment: YESS! Just realized that I was passing pageframes as a string in the main function body to the fifo function. That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be caused by: `queue.append[each]`. Correctly it should be `queue.append(each)`.

EDIT:

tested with python 2.7 it works fine. Here is the code I used for calling just copy-paste and test if it works for you.

```
def fifo(pageframes, pagereferencestring):
    pages = len(pagereferencestring)
    queue = []
    pagefaults = 0

    for each in pagereferencestring:
        if each not in queue:
            pagefaults += 1
            print len(queue)
            print pageframes
            if len(queue) < pageframes:
                print "hello"
                queue.append(each)
            else:
                queue = queue[1:]
                queue.append(each)
            print queue
    print "FIFO mode : " + str(pagefaults)

pageframes = 3
pagereferencestring = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
fifo(pageframes, pagereferencestring)
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't make any difference to the output.

Answer (score 0):

other than changing the print statements because I use python 3.5 I had to adjust your second append statement to use (). It works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. It's giving me the same output even after fixing the append statement. The problem is in the comparison statement.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
I was passing pageframes as a string in the main body, and not an integer. Thus, the comparison was not working corectly, as it wasn't comparing two integers, but an int and a string.